# Channelling DOM0 internet connection through DOMU

Tags: ubuntu, networking, proxy, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-12.04

Bit of an odd queston but wanted to know your opinions on the following:

I have a small computer that has Ubuntu (Both DOM0 and DOMU) virtualized using KVM.

Now the person that will handle this computer will travel with it and can change the DOMU IP address through a web interface, however no access to DOM0 is given and the DOM0 needs to "tunnel/channel/proxy" it's connections through DOMU to ensure it has internet connection whenever the DOMU IP is changed.

How would you go about doing this? Setting up a proxy on DOMU allowing only connections from DOM0? any other ways ? Which IP's would you use for this connection (a provate range to the DOMs only perhaps as to not get in conflict with the outside network) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To set things straight, there are no DOM-whatever in kvm, it's not Xen. So, as I understand, you need to be flexible with the host IP address. This is fairly simple, you have two options (unless you get into SRIOV stuff of course):

1. Use a bridge, and have the bridge use DHCP instead of static addresses. The guest will need to be set with a DHCP as well of course.
2. Use NAT - the host will get an address from the local DHCP, and the guest can stay behind libvirt NAT, using static or dynamic addresses

Comment: hi Dyasny, thanks for the clarification and reply. However I want the Guest to have a flexible IP that can and will be changed via a GUI and  the Host is the one that needs to adapt and connect through the guest.